# Flask sql-alchemy commit not updating user table

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm creating a UI to allow admins to edit registered users and I'm struggling to find a solution to update the data in my table. The route below gets the user id from the previous page and then a query populates the form fields which I can then edit. Then I have an 'if request method' which assigns the form values to the query which I then want to commit to the database. After this it flashes a success message and redirects to the page of users. However, it seems to just skip the db session commit, and flashes the success and performs the redirect.

I'm not getting any errors, but the database isn't being updated, it's like it's not registering the new values when I update the form fields.

Packages being used: Flask SQLALchemy, Flask WTForms. Database is MySQL.

routes.py

```
@admin.route('/admin/edituser/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edituser(id):
    if current_user.is_admin:
        edituserform =  EditUserForm(request.form)
        user_query = User.query.filter_by(id=id).first()

        edituserform.email.data = user_query.email
        edituserform.first_name.data = user_query.first_name
        edituserform.last_name.data = user_query.last_name
        edituserform.is_admin.data = user_query.is_admin
        edituserform.company_name.data = user_query.company_name

        if request.method == 'POST' and edituserform.validate_on_submit:
            user_query.email = edituserform.email.data
            user_query.first_name = edituserform.first_name.data
            user_query.last_name = edituserform.last_name.data
            user_query.is_admin = edituserform.is_admin.data
            user_query.company_name = edituserform.company_name.data

            db.session.commit()
            flash('User has been updated')
            return redirect(url_for('admin.adminusers'))

        return render_template('/admin/edituser.html', title='Edit User', edituserform=edituserform, user_query=user_query)

    return redirect(url_for('store.viewstore'))
```

forms.py

```
class EditUserForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    first_name = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    company_name = QuerySelectField('Select Company', query_factory=lambda:Company.query.all(), get_label="customer_id")
    is_admin = BooleanField('Admin Account?')
    save_user_button = SubmitField('Save Changes')
```

Edit: Just to add, I've tried db.session.add(user_query) and db.session.merge(user_query) before my commit and the same thing happens as above. I tried to db.session.append and it gives me a "AttributeError: 'scoped_session' object has no attribute 'append'" error.

Comment: I think you never changed anything because first you assigned `editeruserform.email.data` to `userquery.email` and then you are assigning `userquery.email` to `editoruserform.email.data` which you defined above. Btw I am not completely sure.

Comment: @charchit That's interesting, I thought because the second part is wrapped in an if statement for when the post action occurs, `userquery.email` would be replaced with whatever is in the form field (because this would change). According to other posts and various youtube searches I was under the impression that what I have should work, but that's obviously not the case!

Comment: Use a if request.method == get when defining these `edituserform.email.data = user_query.email ....` a

Comment: @charchit it now gives me this after adding if....get: sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: <unprintable DataError object>

Comment: Can you edit the code in question which cause this error and on what line mainly the error in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huge thanks to @charchit without your input I could not have solved this.
Your suggestion of using `if request.method == 'GET'` was obviously what I needed to fix the loop I was stuck in when trying to update the existing data with what is changed in the form.

I looked into that new error that got thrown up. The `company_name` in my `User` table is a foreign key to a separate table, so I think when I was trying to update the table it was trying to add a string to an integer. So I put the `company_name` data into a separate variable and then used that variable to append the relationship.

Then it was a simple case of merging the data `db.session.merge(user_query)`. Below is the full code, it might be a bit clunky, but it works now! Again, huge thanks for your help, I don't have many people in my life who I can discuss this stuff with so sometimes it just helps to bounce ideas off someone else.

routes.py

```
@admin.route('/admin/edituser/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edituser(id):
    if current_user.is_admin:
        edituserform =  EditUserForm(request.form)
        user_query = User.query.filter_by(id=id).first()

        if request.method == 'GET':
            edituserform.email.data = user_query.email
            edituserform.first_name.data = user_query.first_name
            edituserform.last_name.data = user_query.last_name
            edituserform.is_admin.data = user_query.is_admin
            edituserform.company_name.data = user_query.company_name
            
        if request.method == 'POST' and edituserform.validate_on_submit:
            user_query.email = edituserform.email.data
            user_query.first_name = edituserform.first_name.data
            user_query.last_name = edituserform.last_name.data
            user_query.is_admin = edituserform.is_admin.data

            company_assign = edituserform.company_name.data # Variable that pulls the company data from the form
            company_assign.user.append(user_query) # Appending the relationship
            db.session.merge(user_query) # Merging the new data with the existing data
            db.session.commit()
            flash('User has been updated')
            return redirect(url_for('admin.adminusers'))

        return render_template('/admin/edituser.html', title='Edit User', edituserform=edituserform, user_query=user_query)

    return redirect(url_for('store.viewstore'))
```